# Are un-upvotes lowering the rep ceiling?

Tags: support, voting, reputation

I have a weird behaviour in SE today, where my daily Rep seems capped at 190, not 200:

[image]

It's not clear to me what causes this behaviour, but earlier today, someone unupvoted a vote:

[image]

Is that expected to be causing such behaviour? If not, what could be the reason? Or is this a bug?Everything else seems perfectly normal, some upvotes, some downvotes etc.

Comment: Is [Duplicated votes are being cleaned up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379788/175002) (MSE) related in any way?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage: there was only an unupvote/upvote and an unaccept/accept on that qeustion (leaving it unchanged in the end, I think) all at around the same time (not sure if I can see that in more detail than the 10 hours ago). There were no other upvotes on it today, so not sure if that could cause a doubled upvote?

Comment: I'm thinking reversing a historical doublevote might have lowered the repcap somehow?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage That cleanup will leave a "voting corrected" message, not unupvote. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379788/upcoming-cleanup-of-duplicated-votes#comment1267311_379854

Comment: It is worth noting that [if you had uncounted upvotes on the day the unupvote was counted toward, you will still get legendary progress for that day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237082/674198), and [the unupvote will not affect potential legendary progress for today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325661/674198).

Answer (score 10):

### Unupvotes aren't counted as part of the day they happened

In short, unupvotes are treated as though the upvote never happened. That means *technically* the rep loss happened to a previous day. However, to stop users worrying about the implications of time travel, the change tracker shows it happening at the day of the unvoting. So today you hit the rep cap of 200, but you also got a -10 rep modification that isn't actually part of the day's rep (see also bounties and accept bonuses).

You can see your actual rep tally on `/reputation`, which should have shown you as having earned 200 rep today (finding when the unupvote was taken from would require a fair bit of investigation, and is probably not worth your time).

Comment: I think that is it -- the /reputation tally shows the number without the unupvote (and unaccept), as +215. Thank you for the explanation.